# Linking MODx MIGx listed results to a more information page

Tags: modx

I'm using MODx CMS with MIGx to list some properties on a page, what i'd like to do is then those to a page with more information on that property.

Is there any way to do this without having to create individual pages for each property?  I know I could do the same thing with GetResource but trying to avoid having 100's of MODx resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial how to do that step by step:

http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/migx/migx.tutorials/migx.simple-opening-hours-table